# Output only one blank line

Tags: common-lisp

`fresh-line` outputs a newline only if we are not already at start of the line, in other words goes to the next line but never produces a blank line, in other words outputs a maximum of one consecutive newline character.

I need a function that outputs a blank line only if we have not just output one already, in other words outputs a maximum of two consecutive newline characters.

Or put another way, I'm looking for an *idempotent* blank-line function, one which will output exactly one blank line even if called several times.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, I think you can use the following property of `fresh-line` (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_terpri.htm#fresh-line)):

> `fresh-line` returns true if it outputs a newline; otherwise it returns false.

to define something like:

```
(defun my-fresh-line ()
  (unless (fresh-line)
    (terpri)))
```

If, on the other hand, you want **always** a blank line after the current written text, be it terminated with a new line or not, you can define something like:

```
(define blank-line ()
  (fresh-line)
  (terpri))
```

and then call it after the current output.

Comment: That successfully outputs a blank line in the case where we were already at the beginning of the line (so `fresh-line` returned false), but in the other case, just goes to the beginning of the line, and does not output a blank line?

Comment: It outputs a newline since this is the behaviour of `fresh-line`, which is called as first thing.

Comment: If you want a blank line in **every** case, you should simply call `(fresh-line)` and then `(terpri)`

Comment: Right, but what I want is an *idempotent* blank-line function, something which will output exactly one blank line even if called several times.

Comment: @rwallace, with `fresh-line` you can only know if the previous line is newline-terminated or not. If `fresh-line` returns `T` you do not know if a blank line has already been emitted or not. To solve your problem one should keep a global state, and then reset it, when necessary. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah, and then write my own output functions that wrap the built-in ones and keep the global state updated; looks like that's what I need to do. Was just wondering if there was an easier way that made more use of the built-in logic, but if not, fair enough.